# Print pdf in applet using itext

Tags: pdf, printing, applet, itext

I have an issue printing pdf file in applet. I got input from http and the stream is consutructed using the pdfstamper. The problem is that i want to send the resulted stream to printer, but i did not find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

UNless the printer supports PDF you cannot send it directly to the printer. You need to rasterize it. I wrote a blog article on printing PDFs from Java at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/

Comment: I understand that PDF-fluent printers are becoming increasingly common, but your point is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

PDFBox might manage it.  I'm not aware of any other Java-specific PDF renderers out there, though I wouldn't be shocked to find there's a couple more out there.

Basically, any app that can convert a PDF to an image can probably act as a print driver.

GhostScript perhaps?

Comment: BigFaceless, Crionics, IcePDF, JPedal, Qoppa, Mulivalent all offer rasterizing/printing. I am obviously biased towards JPedal as I wrote the code.

Comment: Sheesh.  I'd heard of BigFaceless and JPedal.  Senility is setting in early.